# Moving from production site to live

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a site in production and am looking to move it to live this week. The database will be exactly the same, the site will just be moved to a different folder on the server. (Ie from devsite.com to livesite.com)

Is it as simple as copying all the files and putting them on the live site? Or will there be absolute references that will still point to the dev site? Is there anything else I will have problems with in the move?

EDIT: HELP!!! I have performed the change to the DB like it says in the answer below, but it is still redirecting from livesite.com to devsite.com!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few other steps you need to do like updating the URLs in the database.

If you do an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%base_url%';
```

Then update those matches with what ever the new site will be, so if it is http:/ /www.devsite.com and https:/ /www.devsite.com you would update those (one is secure the other is insecure) to http:/ /www.livesite.com and https:/ /www.livesite.com. If nothing else is chaniging like the database user, or the database name then you don't need to change the app/etc/local.xml file, if you are changing any of that data then you need to update that file to contain the user, password, and database name.

Comment: OK I have uploaded all the files to the live server. Renamed index.php so I can keep a holding page there for the time being. All I have to do, come the live date, is rename the index.php back again and change the urls in the query above? It feels like it should be more difficult...

Comment: Yep, a more detailed view of creating a staging site from a production site can be read [here](http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/setting-up-a-magento-staging-area/).

Comment: AHHHH!!! I have made this change but when I go to www.livesite.com it redirects to www.devsite.com! HELP!!!

Comment: Don't mind me, clearing the cache seems to have worked! Phew!

Comment: You should add, that there might be hard coded links for js_basedir, skin_basedir, etc. So if all these special basedirs are set, this query is not enough.